# set css rule: direct all links to only one page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, xhtml

Is there a way to write a CSS rule for HTML that assigns all links on my web page to the same destination no matter if in the `<a href="...">` block there is a different destination defined?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use CSS (styling) to change the content (HTML). You could use it to hide all `a` elements and replace them with something else, using JavaScript, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with CSS. You would have to use JavaScript or a server-side language.

Comment: Piggybacking off @TylerH, you could hide all links on the page, and use the :before or :after pseudo to replace those with content.

Answer (score 2):

Natively, CSS does not support changing attributes; however, this can be done with jQuery:

```
$("a[href]").attr("href", "http://www.example.com");
```

This will change all `<a>` elements that have an `href` attribute and set them to link to example.com.

---

If you want to include *all* `<a>` elements, just remove `[href]` from the selector:

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: Nice but change $(a[href]) with $('a[href]') otherwise it wont work!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the answers - I asked my teacher (who assigned the task) and he confirmed, that it was an error, he meant to make us write such a rule in html and not css. So most of your answers are confirmed :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using CSS, however i would like to mention this:

```
a{ pointer-events: none; }
```

This is the closest to what you are looking for ~ it will block "href" links but wont be able to redirect.

jQuery Solution:

```
$('a[href]').attr("href", "http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: Edit: @David method is better in terms of jQuery.